# Using two python paths for vim in Windows

Tags: windows, vim, python, path

I wanted to simply `:!python %` in order to run the file im using in vim, but the obvious conflict is that there's no way for me to distinguish python2 and python3 since including both to `$PATH$` would result in two instances of `python.exe`.

Is there an elegant solution to this? I just want a quick way to run what I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define two custom commands, e.g.:

```
:command! Python2 !C:\python2\python %
:command! Python3 !C:\python3\python %
```

Alternatively, in case the Python version differs per project, I'd use one of the *local vimrc* plugins to set a buffer-local variable (say, `b:python_version`), and check that in a custom command:

```
:command! Python execute '!C:\python' . b:python_version . '\python %'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no *obvious* conflict as it doesn't matter how many `python.exe`s you have in your `PATH`, **only the first one would be executed**.  The `PATH` works from left to right - once the executable is found, the process is invoked and the search discontinues.

So if you have `C:\python27\` before `C:\python3\`, you would **always** execute python2.

> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))
>   When a command is entered in a command shell or a system call is made
>   by a program to execute a program, the system first searches the
>   current working directory and then searches the path, examining each
>   directory from left to right, looking for an executable filename that
>   matches the command name given. Executable programs have filename
>   extensions of EXE or COM, and batch scripts have extensions of BAT or
>   CMD. Other executable filename extensions can be registered with the
>   system as well.
>
> Once a matching executable file is found, the system spawns a new
>   process in which to run it.

As a solution to this, I would agree with [@IngoKarkat](https://superuser.com/users/117820/ingo-karkat)'s solution - however, I would put that in my `~/.vimrc` instead.

Comment: There's already a `:python3` command built-in (when compiled with Python 3 support); in any case, custom commands must start with an uppercase letter.